# Indigo ARM wet build on Beaglebone Black

Tags: robotic-arm, build, ubuntu, source, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have gotten fairly far along in building a Ubuntu 14.04 Indigo on a beaglebone Black and the install went through the 'robot' rosdep install http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source.

As a matter of fact I see this:

ubuntu@arm:~/ros_catkin_ws/src/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg$ ls
CameraInfo.msg       JoyFeedback.msg         PointCloud.msg
ChannelFloat32.msg   JoyFeedbackArray.msg    PointCloud2.msg
CompressedImage.msg  LaserEcho.msg           PointField.msg
FluidPressure.msg    LaserScan.msg           Range.msg
Illuminance.msg      MagneticField.msg       RegionOfInterest.msg
Image.msg            MultiDOFJointState.msg  RelativeHumidity.msg
Imu.msg              MultiEchoLaserScan.msg  Temperature.msg
JointState.msg       NavSatFix.msg           TimeReference.msg
Joy.msg              NavSatStatus.msg

I see this after installing ros_arduino_bridge and rebuilding via rosdep.

ubuntu@arm:~$ locate sensor_msgs|grep Range
/home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/msg/Range.msg
/home/ubuntu/ros_catkin_ws/src/genmsg/test/files/sensor_msgs/msg/Range.msg

so it isn't anywhere in the executable path.

Here is where it complains during launch:

/ros_arduino_python/arduino_sensors.py", line 24, in 
from sensor_msgs.msg import Range
ImportError: No module named sensor_msgs.msg

so

rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y

gives one error message:

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package collada-dom-dev
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y collada-dom-dev] failed

after a apt-get and rosdep update the same error occurs.

Not a major or urgent issue for me, just trying to learn how things work by kicking the tires.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193582/indigo-arm-wet-build-on-beaglebone-black/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2014-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you're only at the rosdep stage, nothing has been built. It's just resolving system dependencies. You need to continue down the instructions to get to the build step.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0